OneDrive in Azure VM
I am a bit new in Azure. What I am trying to accomplish is to have a VM, which has OneDrive installed, and use runbooks to turn it on, run python scripts, that are stored in a SharePoint folder, which will use apis to query some info and create files to store in another SharePoint folder. Then turn it off.
The thing is at the moment I am able to run the scripts but it fails to sync, unless I connect to it, which I would like to avoid as I want it to be a automated process.
Here is my code for the runbook, above I have the routes in the VM:
# Function to run a Python script
function Run-PythonScript {
    param (
        [string]$PythonExecutable,
        [string]$ScriptPath
    )

    $escapedScriptPath = $ScriptPath -replace '\\', '\\\\'

    $command = @"
& '$PythonExecutable' '$escapedScriptPath'
"@

    try {
        $response = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptString $command -ErrorAction Stop

        if ($response) {
            $response.Value | ForEach-Object {
                $logMessage = "Command execution output for ${ScriptPath}: " + $_.Message
                Write-Output $logMessage
            }
        } else {
            $noResponseMessage = "No response received from the VM command execution for ${ScriptPath}."
            Write-Output $noResponseMessage
        }
    } catch {
        $errorMessage = "Error executing ${ScriptPath}: $_"
        Write-Output $errorMessage
    }
}

# Main Script Execution

# Login to Azure using Managed Identity
$AzureContext = (Get-AzContext)
if ($AzureContext -eq $null) {
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}

# Run OneDrive sync script
Write-Output "Running OneDrive sync script..."
Run-PythonScript -PythonExecutable $PythonExecutable -ScriptPath $OneDriveSyncScript

# Run all other scripts sequentially
foreach ($scriptPath in $ScriptPaths) {
    Run-PythonScript -PythonExecutable $PythonExecutable -ScriptPath $scriptPath
}

# Log completion of the runbook
$runbookCompletedMessage = "Runbook execution completed."
Write-Output $runbookCompletedMessage

So I have tried a lot of different situations with the Runbooks, like trying to execute OneDrive file, but it tells me that the file is not there, or the folder is not there.
Any recommendations? Or maybe a change in the approach?
Thanks in advance

Have you tried simpler API calls, like listing files on the OneDrive? I have no experience with what you are trying to achieve, but running files, through an interpreter, on a remote server can fail for many reasons, from incorrect paths to security and many others. Without more specific knowledge on your exact setup, it's very difficult to know what's happening. You should try to describe precisely what works and what doesn't and provide more traces about how you reached those conclusions
